# Sistema de multiplas escolhas em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Pessoal estou fazendo o seguinte a seguinte função em um Web Site:
XXX-A | XXX-B | XXX-C | XXX-D
Quando a pessoa clicar no XXX-A vai aparecer somente a DIV com conteúdo A e assim sucessivamente... Porém eu consegui fazer o conteúdo A aparecer mas não consigo fazer os outros desaparecerem, segue abaixo o código:

```js
  function MudarMethod() {
   const content01 = document.getElementById('content01');

   if(document.GetElementById('content2').style.display == 'block')
      document.GetElementById('content3').style.display == 'block')
      document.GetElementById('content4').style.display == 'block')
      {
       document.GetElementById('content2').style.display = 'none'
       document.GetElementById('content3').style.display = 'none'
       document.GetElementById('content4').style.display = 'none'
       content01.style.display = 'block'
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', () => MudarMethod());
```

```css
#content01 {
 display: none;
}

#content02 {
 display: block;
}

#content03 {
 display: none;
}

#content04 {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
 <div class="background-content">
  <div class="align-content">
   <h1>Métodos de ensino</h1>
   <div id="methodlearn">
    <button id="button1">XXX</button>
    <button id="button2">XXX</button>
    <button id="button3">XXX</button>
    <button id="button4">XXX</button>
    <div id="content01">Conteúdo 01</div>
    <div id="content02">Conteúdo 02</div>
    <div id="content03">Conteúdo 03</div>
    <div id="content04">Conteúdo 04</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Eu coloquei o display:block no content 2 para somente fazer o teste e ver se está pegando.

Obrigado pessoal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa usar tantos id's para isso. Apenas com `class` é possível e bem mais simples. Note que ainda há um erro de sintaxe no seu código:

O "get" em `document.GetElementById` é minúsculo -> `document.getElementById`

Use uma `class` nos botões e uma `class` nas divs dos conteúdos. Por exemplo, nos botões você coloca `class="btn"` e nas divs `class="content"`:

```
<div id="methodlearn">
   <button class="btn">1</button>
   <button class="btn">2</button>
   <button class="btn">3</button>
   <button class="btn">4</button>
   <div class="content">Conteúdo 01</div>
   <div class="content">Conteúdo 02</div>
   <div class="content">Conteúdo 03</div>
   <div class="content">Conteúdo 04</div>
</div>
```

Como a intenção é de que cada botão esteja relacionado a uma div, fica bem fácil ao clicar no botão "1" e mostrar a primeira div; clicar no botão "2" e mostrar a segunda div, e assim sucessivamente. Você só precisa achar o *index* (índice) do botão clicado.

Como são 4 botões com a mesma classe, o primeiro é index `0`, o segundo index `1` etc. A mesma coisa com as divs. A primeira div com a classe "content" é index `0`, a segunda index `1` etc... Logo, se você descobrir o index do botão clicado, você pode encontrar a div relacionada.

Basta criar um *event handler* `onclick` para cada botão, achar o index do botão através de um laço `for` e mostrar a div com o mesmo index, e usar outro `for` para esconder as outras.

E no CSS, basta colocar `.content{ display: none; }` para ocultar todas as divs de uma vez.

Veja como fica (coloquei alguns comentários no código pra facilitar o entendimento):

```js
// seleciona todos os botões pela classe
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for(var bts_ of btns){
   
   bts_.onclick = function(){
      
      // seleciona todos os botões com a classe .btn dentro de #methodlearn
      var childs = document.querySelectorAll("#methodlearn .btn");
      var index = 0;
      
      // determina o index do botão com base 0
      for(var el of childs){
         if(this == el) break;
         index++;
      }
      
      var contents = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
      
      // esconde todos
      for(var cts_ of contents){
         cts_.style.display = "none";
      }
      
      // mostra só a div do botão que foi clicado
      contents[index].style.display = "block";
      
   }
   
}
```

```css
.content{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-content">
   <div class="align-content">
      <h1>Métodos de ensino</h1>
      <div id="methodlearn">
         <button class="btn">1</button>
         <button class="btn">2</button>
         <button class="btn">3</button>
         <button class="btn">4</button>
         <div class="content">Conteúdo 01</div>
         <div class="content">Conteúdo 02</div>
         <div class="content">Conteúdo 03</div>
         <div class="content">Conteúdo 04</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sam, achei seu método de explicação incrível parabéns!

Eu fiquei com dúvida referente ao seguinte for:

    for(var el of childs) {
     if(this == el) break;
     index++;
    } o que você quis dizer com if(this == el)? Esse this é o childs? Fico muito grato pelo seu comentário

Comment: Valeu. O this é o botão que chamou o evento onclick. Nesse for eu verifico se o botão que chamou o evento é igual a um dos botões da coleção.